# Sql query 1 to many with different row condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a query that depends on multiple rows in a referenced table, but should only return a single row per base table.

Given the following example data

If table `person` has rows:

```
id, email
1, 1@email.com
2, 2@email.com
3, 3@email.com
4, 4@email.com
5, 5@email.com
```

and table `B` has rows:

```
id, maincode, subcode, is_obsolete
1, code1,a, null 
2, code1,b, null
3, code2,a, true
4, code2,b, true
5, code3,a, null
6, code4,b, null
7, code5,c, true
```

Table `access_B` has rows:

```
id, person_id, b_id, removed_at
1,1,1,null
2,1,2,null
3,1,3,null
4,1,4,null
5,2,3,null
6,2,4,null
7,3,5,null
8,4,5,null
9,4,7,null
10,5,7,2021-06-10 10:00:00
```

One such query would be

`access_B`  with `removed_at = null` and list a `person` that has a `B` with `is_obsolete = true` **and** a `B` with `is_obsolete = null`. Expected result:

```
   person_email, id, person_id, b_id, removed_at
   1@email.com,1, 1, 1,null
   1@email.com,2, 1, 2,null
   1@email.com,3, 1, 3,null
   1@email.com,4, 1, 4,null
```

There are other similar queries, but with a solution for the first one, the others should be doable.
For completeness, the other queries are:

2. `access_B` with `removed_at = null` that list a person that **ONLY** has B with `is_obsolete = true`. Expected result:

   ```
   person_email, id, person_id, b_id, removed_at
   2@email.com,5,2,3,null
   2@email.com,6,2,4,null
   ```
3. `access_B` with `removed_at = null` that list a `person` that can have `B` with `is_obsolete = true`. Expected result:

   ```
   person_email, id, person_id, b_id, removed_at
   1@email.com,1,1,1,null
   1@email.com,2,1,2,null
   1@email.com,3,1,3,null
   1@email.com,4,1,4,null
   2@email.com,5,2,3,null
   2@email.com,6,2,4,null
   ```

With my limited SQL skills,
I am only able to manage list `access_B` with `removed_at = null` for `person` that has `B` with `is_obsolete = true`.
Result:

```
1@email.com,3,1,3,null
1@email.com,4,1,4,null
2@email.com,5,2,3,null
2@email.com,6,2,4,null
```

```sql
SELECT p.email person_email, ab.* FROM access_B ab 
    JOIN person p ON p.id = access_B.person_id 
    JOIN B ON B.id = access_B.b_id
    WHERE b.is_obsolete IS true and access_B.removed_at is null;
```

Comment: Please yourself to one question per post. Edit this question to clearly state the one question that you want help with

Answer (score 0):

I believe your expected result for first data set is incorrect.  With that said, here is my stab at answering your question.  First here is the data setup for SQL Server.  Please note using BIT type for boolean value:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON (ID INTEGER, EMAIL VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE B (ID INTEGER, MAINCODE VARCHAR(10), SUBCODE CHAR(1), IS_OBSOLETE BIT);
CREATE TABLE ACCESS_B (ID INTEGER, PERSON_ID INTEGER, B_ID INTEGER, REMOVED_AT DATETIME);

INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (1, '1@email.com');
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (2, '2@email.com');
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (3, '3@email.com');
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (4, '4@email.com');
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (5, 't@email.com');

INSERT INTO B VALUES (1, 'code1', 'a', null);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (2, 'code1', 'b', null);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 'code2', 'a', 1);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (4, 'code2', 'b', 1);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (5, 'code3', 'a', null);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (6, 'code4', 'b', null);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (7, 'code5', 'c', 1);

INSERT INTO ACCESS_B VALUES (1, 1, 1, null);
INSERT INTO ACCESS_B VALUES (2, 1, 2, null);
INSERT INTO ACCESS_B VALUES (3, 1, 3, null);
INSERT INTO ACCESS_B VALUES (4, 1, 4, null);
INSERT INTO ACCESS_B VALUES (5, 2, 3, null);
INSERT INTO ACCESS_B VALUES (6, 2, 4, null);
INSERT INTO ACCESS_B VALUES (7, 3, 5, null);
INSERT INTO ACCESS_B VALUES (8, 4, 5, null);
INSERT INTO ACCESS_B VALUES (9, 4, 7, null);
INSERT INTO ACCESS_B VALUES (10, 5, 7, '2021-06-10 10:00:00');
```

1. Scenario 1

access_B with removed_at = null and list a person that has a B with is_obsolete = true and a B with is_obsolete = null

```
SELECT p.email as person_email, acc.id, acc.person_id, acc.b_id, acc.removed_at
FROM ACCESS_B acc
  INNER JOIN PERSON p on p.ID = acc.PERSON_ID
WHERE acc.REMOVED_AT IS NULL
  AND p.ID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT PERSON_ID FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT p.ID as PERSON_ID, b.IS_OBSOLETE
    FROM PERSON p
      INNER JOIN ACCESS_B acc on acc.PERSON_ID = p.ID
      INNER JOIN B b on b.ID = acc.B_ID
    GROUP BY p.ID, b.IS_OBSOLETE
    ) FILT
    GROUP BY PERSON_ID HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
);
```

Results of that query are:

```
person_email, id, person_id, b_id, removed_at
1@email.com,1, 1, 1,null
1@email.com,2, 1, 2,null
1@email.com,3, 1, 3,null
1@email.com,4, 1, 4,null
4@email.com,8, 4, 5,null
4@email.com,9, 4, 7,null
```

2. Scenario 2

access_B with removed_at = null that list a person that ONLY has B with is_obsolete = true

```
SELECT p.email as person_email, acc.id, acc.person_id, acc.b_id, acc.removed_at
FROM ACCESS_B acc
  INNER JOIN PERSON p on p.ID = acc.PERSON_ID
WHERE acc.REMOVED_AT IS NULL
  AND p.ID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT p.ID
    FROM PERSON p
      INNER JOIN ACCESS_B acc on acc.PERSON_ID = p.ID
      INNER JOIN B b on b.ID = acc.B_ID
    WHERE b.IS_OBSOLETE = 1
  )
  AND p.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT p.ID
    FROM PERSON p
      INNER JOIN ACCESS_B acc on acc.PERSON_ID = p.ID
      INNER JOIN B b on b.ID = acc.B_ID
    WHERE b.IS_OBSOLETE IS NULL
  );
```

Results of that query are:

```
person_email, id, person_id, b_id, removed_at
2@email.com,5,2,3,null
2@email.com,6,2,4,null
```

Leaving the remaining queries for you to write yourself.  If you cannot figure them out, ping me on a comment and I will do the rest of them.  Good luck!